# New HTML Data Append cannot be selected by Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, simple-html-dom

I append Data received from Ajax, it also contains a divison with class bsubmit.
When the page loads then if i click on the div containing class bsubit the below function executes But when i click on the new appended data which also contains class bsubmit then the below code isn't working.

Here is the code

```
     $(function() {
    $(".bsubmit").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    var comm= document.getElementById(id).getElementsByClassName("commentadd")[0].value;


      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "comment.php",
       data: {id:id, comm:comm},
       cache: false,
       success: function(data){
        $('.addcomment').slideUp('slow', function() {

        });

// Bottom Line not working

        $("#"+id).find(".item_comment").append(data);   // DATA Contains a div with class bsubmit
         $(data).appendTo("#"+id).find(".item_comment"); // Now these Appended Div isnt calling this function again,  Why ? I want to call them again
        $('#load').fadeOut();
      }

     });


    return false;
        });


    });
```

Comment: There is no possibility to understand what function you wish to re-execute.

Comment: @VisioN. He thinks `appendTo` return the parent, it does not...

Comment: What do you want to happen and doesn't happen.

Comment: @gdoron Ha! Have you seen the update? :)

Comment: @VisioN - 
When the page loads then if i click on the div containing class bsubit the below function executes But when i click on the new appended data which also contains class bsubmit then the below code isn't working.

Comment: [Read this](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F)

Comment: @VisioN. Yes I have, bad worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are binding a click event to the `.bsubmit` class, but that click event gets attacked only to the `.bsubmit` already in the document, not the newly created ones.

So, what you need to do is, either use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) depending on your Jquery version.

## Change this line:

```
$(".bsubmit").click(function() {
```

## to

**Jquery LIVE**

```
$(".bsubmit").live("click", function() {
```

## or

**Jquery ON**

```
$(".bsubmit").on("click", function() {
```

Comment: the last example is actually a nowadays 'replica' of the `.bind()` method. To get a `.live()` using `.on()` you should add after `'click'` the target element.

Comment: The target element is added if not bidding to the "self", but I'm following the OPs method, changing only whats needed to fix his problem!

Comment: @Zuul -You are  Amazing!! 
Thank you  :) 

What was wrong with my statement ?

Comment: @AdiMathur. You got the same answer from Roco, 45 minutes ago, but he showed you with `on` which is better than `live` that now is deprecated. And the `on` version being displayed here is incorrect. it will not create a delegate event!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you question: Have you tried with the `.on()` method? (jQuery 1.7)

```
$(yourParentElement).on('click','.bsubmit',function() {
```

Comment: It has three big problems, **1.** `on` is from jQuery `1.7` **2.** `document` is a bad place of the event **3.** it doesn't help the guy... :)

Comment: Yep, possibly we don't understand the question together.

Comment: @roko - 
When the page loads then if i click on the div containing class bsubit the below function executes But when i click on the new appended data which also contains class bsubmit then the below code isn't working.

Comment: @gdoron the 1.6.8+ was to indicate : GREATER version. Reedited to be more understandable and correct. Thanks

Comment: I removed my downvote because apparently you were right, though the two first comments are still true.

Comment: @gdoron I'm reading the jQ faq link you posted. Apparently the issue lies there.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. Yeah I know, if he could just word it better I would post an answer, but that question is a mess.

Comment: @gdoron I perfectly agree, was about to upvote your effort to resolve this mistery but you removed the A. Undo please. Might be useful to someone, or might be to the OP after a second look :)

Answer (score 1):

`appendTo` doesn't return the parent.

```
$("#"+id).find(".item_comment").append(data);   
$(data).appendTo("#"+id).parent().find(".item_comment"); // Use "parent()"
$('#load').fadeOut();
```

But you really should cache some of the DOM elements...

```
var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
```

Change to:

```
var $parent = $(this).parent().parent();
```

And then:

```
$("#"+id).find(".item_comment").append(data);
```

Change to:

```
$parent.find(".item_comment").append(data);
```

Comment: When the page loads then if i click on the div containing class bsubit the below function executes But when i click on the new appended data which also contains class bsubmit then the below code isn't working.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. Wow it's so wrong! :( a stupid thing here is SO, the questioner which probably know very little on his problem choose what is the correct answer. :( it's so stupid!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan. I left him a comment there, I hope he will notice.